# Sharepoint Hierarchical Structure

Tags: list, folder, library, sub-site

I'm interested in having a hierarchical data set of folders, files, sub-sites etc. from a certain site that I would eventually manipulate/visualize in R. (Data.trees and such) I've done this effectively with all of the folders/sub-folders/files on the site, but I've realized that I don't really understand how sites, libraries, lists etc. feed into one another.

Obviously we have folder->sub-folder... and site->sub-site..., but are libraries always within sites? Can each type be interchangeable stored in the other? Is there a clear hierarchy for me to try and navigate, or is the structure something more abstract? Any other input on going about this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously we have folder->sub-folder... and site->sub-site..., but are libraries always within sites?

Yes, all the content (lists, libraries, items and documents) are always located within sites.

> Is there a clear hierarchy for me to try and navigate, or is the structure something more abstract?

From content perspective, everything has strict hierarchy.

Check these these two links : [link-1](https://sharepointmaven.com/structure-sites-sharepoint-intranet/) and [link-2](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/building-a-good-information-architecture-in-sharepoint). First explains more about site hierarchy and other focuses on whole structure (from web application till documents).